How can I purge (completely delete) a Google Calendar Event
I created an event using some test data in Google Calendar's node API while trying to test out a program I'm building. Now I'm ready to move to the next stage but can't because when trying to create a new event it says it already exists. When I call get on the eventId it returns an event with the following info
{
        "kind": "calendar#event",
       "transparency": "transparent",
        "iCalUID": "495663@google.com"
        "id": "495663",
        "status": "cancelled",
        "start": {
                "dateTime": "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
                "dateTime": "2000-01-02T00:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
}


However when I try to call delete on that event it gives an error that the event ~doesn't exist~ has been deleted.
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "deleted",
    "message": "Resource has been deleted"
   }
  ],
  "code": 410,
  "message": "Resource has been deleted"
 }
}


When going to Google Calendar in the browser I don't see the event anywhere, not even in the deleted events section.
I read somewhere that I can always update the event status to confirmed for it to be visible, but my question is more how can I delete the event properly, permanently and avoid this situation happening again.

Can you show, how you are creating a new event? This might be where your error is coming from. Especially all parameters you have used on the request body. The response you've shown from the GET method is how it was supposed to be.

I'm creating it using the Insert API.  According to the doc
"All [other] cancelled events represent deleted events. Clients should remove their locally synced copies. Such cancelled events will eventually disappear, so do not rely on them being available indefinitely.
Deleted events are only guaranteed to have the id field populated. "
Which leads me to believe is what's going on, which is why the date is 2000 since i set it for 2024

Thank you for your reply Rhahkeem. It is hard to replicate your question without any information with your code and request body. Though with your case it shouldn't be a problem since in every creation of an event there is a new event object that will be created and it will have a unique event ID.

I'm having the same issue. it seems that once you have transformed an instance into an exception - which is an actual rather than virtual event - it is not possible to delete the exception. Using the Calendar.Events.remove method from the Google service just sets status to cancelled; resetting all the properties to their original values still leaves the exception as an event in Calendar.Events.list. So once you have edited any instance in any way it turns into an exception which is thereafter treated as an event an you are stuck with that.
